# Byte Array, when converted to string, then concatenated, returns equal String but unequal byte array

Tags: java, arrays, string, byte, delimiter

I have a byte array. I need to concatenate a string with a delimiter to it. Then I want to get back the byte array. After all this logic, the output byte array is not equal to the input. In java:

This fails at the last line:

```
    @Test
    void test1() {
        byte[] initialBytes = RandomUtils.nextBytes(64);
        String initialString = new String(initialBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        String concatenatedString = String.join("\t", "Pre", initialString);
        byte[] concatenatedStringToBytes = concatenatedString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        String concatenatedBytesBackToString = new String(concatenatedStringToBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        int indexOfDelimeter = concatenatedBytesBackToString.indexOf("\t");
        String finalString = concatenatedBytesBackToString.substring(indexOfDelimeter + 1);

        byte[] finalBytes = finalString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        assertEquals(initialString, finalString);
        assertTrue(Arrays.equals(initialBytes, finalBytes));
    }
```

Comment: Two possibilities.  Either your randomly generated bytes don't represent a valid `String`, or they represent a `String` which has more than one possible UTF-8 representation.

Comment: Isn't `Arrays.equals(initialBytes, finalBytes)` being false a very possible and valid result?

Comment: @sarveshseri - It is, but the strings corresponding to those byte arrays are equal. So I was confused why the byte[] are unequal.

Comment: Change it to dump both the byte arrays when they are unequal and have a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `String` values use `UTF_16`.

Since `UTF_16` and `UTF_8` have different character coverage, conversions from `UTF_8` to `UTF_16` can result in loss of information (if those non-matching characters are used). So, when you convert back to `UTF_8`, you will not get the same byte array.

```java
public static void tryCharsetEncodingForRandomBytes() {
    byte[] initialBytes = getRandomBytes(64);
    String initialString = new String(initialBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    byte[] finalBytes = initialString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String finalString = new String(finalBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    System.out.println(finalString.equals(initialString));
    System.out.println(initialBytes.length);
    System.out.println(finalBytes.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(initialBytes, finalBytes));
}
```

Output :

```
true
64
103
false
```

You will not encounter this loss of information when dealing with more popular characrers like AlphaNumerics which are commons in both `UTF_16` and `UTF_8` charsets.

```java
public static void tryCharsetEncodingForAlphanumeric() {
    String alphaNumeric = "abcd1234";

    byte[] initialBytes = alphaNumeric.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String initialString = new String(initialBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    byte[] finalBytes = initialString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String finalString = new String(finalBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    System.out.println(finalString.equals(initialString));
    System.out.println(initialBytes.length);
    System.out.println(finalBytes.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(initialBytes, finalBytes));
}
```

Output:

```
true
8
8
true
```

Which means that your tests will pass as long as you are dealing with common characters in `UTF_8` and `UTF_16`.

```java
public static void yourTestScenarioWithAlphaNumeric() {
    String alphaNumeric = "abcdefghijklmop1234567890";

    byte[] initialBytes = alphaNumeric.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String initialString = new String(initialBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    String concatenatedString = String.join("\t", "Pre", initialString);
    byte[] concatenatedStringToBytes = concatenatedString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    String concatenatedBytesBackToString = new String(concatenatedStringToBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    int indexOfDelimiter = concatenatedBytesBackToString.indexOf("\t");
    String finalString = concatenatedBytesBackToString.substring(indexOfDelimiter + 1);

    byte[] finalBytes = finalString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    System.out.println(finalString.equals(initialString));
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(initialBytes, finalBytes));
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
```